# Is $T:= \{g \in A_4|g^2 =(1)\}$ a subgroup of $A_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Consider the subset 
$$T:= \{g \in A_4|g^2 =(1)\}$$
of the alternating group $A_4$ in four letters. Is T a subgroup of $A_4$?

My Proof:
Yes. If I am not wrong T is the Klein 4-group since only (1),(14)(23),(12)(34) and (13)(24) are of order 2.

1. Identity is in T.
2. For all $x\in T$, $x\in A_4$ and $x^2 = (1)$. Hence $x = x^{-1}$ and therefore $x^{-1} \in A_4$ and $(x^{-1})^2 =(1)$. $x^{-1}$ is in $T$.
3. **Need help to prove xy in T.**

Comment: For such a small set, you can just work out the multiplication table.

Comment: I know but I want to know how I can prove it without using multiplication table. That is more useful for me in the future if i encounter larger group

Comment: It is indeed the klein 4 group, and you can pretty simply show the multiplication table is such, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x,y\in T$.
From (2.) in your proof, one obtains
$$xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}=(yx)^{-1}=yx\text,\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{($\ast$)}$$
which implies
$$(xy)^2=xyxy\underset{\text{($\ast$)}}=xy^2x=x^2=1\text,$$
hence $xy\in T$.